# How do I remove postfix numbers from material UI classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is default class for material ui input box `.MuiInputBase-input`, when I check from the developer tools the same class is available as `.MuiInputBase-input-619` like this. How can I remove the postfix of the class. I am using `material-core:^4.11.4` version. Please help me in this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These classNames are used by Material UI and changing them will result in inconsistency and UI discrepancies.

If you want to override certain stylings, then you can use the root class or the class names mentioned in the documentation under APIs of a component.

You can even your own class and then override the underlying classes.